# Remarkable 2 app not working on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, wine

I recently bought a remarkable 2 writing tablet primarily to write down my calculations and do a live screen share with my students whom I may have to lecture remotely.

I discovered that remarkable 2 app that is needed to share screens used to have a version for ubuntu which does not work any more - remarkable support it only for windows and MAC is there a user here who has managed to do it succesfully ?

I tried this
[https://snapcraft.io/install/remarkable-desktop/ubuntu#:~:text=The%20reMarkable%20desktop%20application%20enables,when%20connected%20to%20Wi%2DFi](https://snapcraft.io/install/remarkable-desktop/ubuntu#:%7E:text=The%20reMarkable%20desktop%20application%20enables,when%20connected%20to%20Wi%2DFi)
and also wine :
https://www.reddit.com/r/RemarkableTablet/comments/s3tza2/how_to_use_the_remarkable_app_with_linux_wine/

thanks
Farrukh